# how to know that an app was launch from a click to a notification in the system tray?

Tags: android, firebase, android-intent, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

When I send an alert notification, if the app is either not running or is in the background, the alert terminates in the system tray. Then later the user clicks on this notification and the app is launched. How can I know that the app was launched from a click on a notification alert in the system tray? And how can I retrieve the information regarding this notification? Also, not that I'm using Firebase cloud messaging.

Comment: You can put a Bundle Extra in the Intent that launches the Starting Activity. If the Intent has this Extra, it means the App was launched from the Notification

Comment: @MayorJay but how to add this Bundle extra? I sent the message from google firebase messaging

Answer (score 0):

These similar posts explain how to send and receive messages in the intent:

- [How to handle notification when app in background in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37845174/20447561)
- [get Intent Extra from clicking notification through Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60917161/20447561)